# How to calculate no of days in a month? User to enter the no of the month

Tags: java, calendar

How to calculate no of days in a month? User to enter the no of the month.
I have written a piece of code for the above, and want to know if its appropriate.

```
public class Exercise{


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Input a month number:");
        Scanner scan ;
        int month = 1; int monthName = 1;
        while(month < 12 && month > 0) {
            scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            monthName = scan.nextInt();

            month= monthName-1;
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM", Locale.US);     
            Calendar mycal = Calendar.getInstance();
            mycal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2017);
            mycal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            int numDays = mycal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE);
            System.out.println(" The no of days in the month of is "+ " "+ numDays);
        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not appropriate?

Comment: Did you try executing it yourself? https://ideone.com/aFAf3t

Comment: I'm not sure what are your try to do.

Comment: Yes, it is correct if you want this for the current year as the difference will be when there is a leap year.

Comment: You should not hardcode the year 2017 but the current year (it might be a leap year which causes a difference in February).

Comment: @MenoHochschild maybe it's not _meant_ to give the month lengths for the current year but only for 2017?  We haven't been told the requirements (:->)

Comment: (1) No need to create a scanner for each iteration, just one before the loop. (2) Don’t declare a variable until you need it; declare `monthName` inside the loop. (3) If you’re not using `df` for anything, delete that line. (4) `Calendar` is long outdated. You want the `YearMonth` class and its `lengthOfMonth` method.